# Adding custom widget to GLADE

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glade

Hi am using gtk3 and glade 3.14...I want to add a custom widget to glade so that i can add that to my user interface easily.

I found knob widget is missing in glade and i found knob widget in

http://sourceforge.net/projects/giw/

I downloaded and installed instrumentation widgets but it wont get added to Glade.

Is a knob widget available in glade.

I tried using the knob.c and knob.h file and tried example and got some examples working but couldn't integrate them to gade.

Answer (score 5):

What you need is a `glade catalog file` which describes your widgets properties, the catalog name and a few other things. You may also have to add an additional catalog path under `Edit > Preferences` in the dialog section where it says `Extra Catalog Paths` if the catalog resides outside of the default lookup paths.

[For details on how to create a catalog, read the catalogintro.](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gladeui/stable/catalogintro.html)

Comment: It's not clear how can i add my custom widhet to glade

Comment: You need to write a catalog file yourself, that is the requirement - without it won't show up.

Comment: You "don't get it" you write it yourself if the project does not provide it.

Comment: i didnt understand what is a dtd file usually when we create a glade project we get a glade file then we acces it from main.c what is  dtd file

Comment: of the widget so glade can display them properly and map it back to xml which will be used to create widgets with `GtkBuilder`.  This and much more is explained in the catalogintro which I linked to in the answer. So go forth and RTM.

Comment: See more a HOWTO/more recent answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1471492/78169)