# "Invalid object type" When using a custom widget in Gtk.Builder ui file

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

Consider the following:

```
class MyCustomWidget : Gtk.Widget {
    public MyCustomWidget () {
        Object ();
    }
}

void main (string args[]) {
    string ui_string = """
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <interface>
        <object class="MyCustomWidget">
        </object>
    </interface>
    """;

    Gtk.init (ref args);    
    Gtk.Builder builder = new Gtk.Builder.from_string (ui_string, ui_string.length);
}
```

I am creating a custom Widget derived from Gtk.Widget. When using this widget with Gtk.Builder, I get the following error and the program crashes:

```
(bla:22282): Gtk-ERROR **: failed to add UI: .:4:1 Invalid object type 'MyCustomWidget'
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the type MyCustomWidget is not yet known to Gtk.Builder. This is why custom widgets should be **instantiated at least once before being used with Gtk.Builder**. This instance can then be thrown away.

```
void main (string args[]) {
    string ui_string = """
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <interface>
        <object class="MyCustomWidget">
        </object>
    </interface>
    """;

    Gtk.init (ref args);
    // create a throw-away instance of MyCustomWidget
    var tmp = new MyCustomWidget ();   
    Gtk.Builder builder = new Gtk.Builder.from_string (ui_string, ui_string.length);
}
```

Comment: Does Vala have a way to register the class without creating a new object, equivalent to calling the `classname_get_type()` function in C? Will the object be destroyed immediately? (I have not used Vala in a while...)

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219788/adding-custom-widget-to-glade

Comment: @JoséFonte no, because that answer is about using custom widgets in the glade UI editor, not in actual code

Comment: @stunningpotato So what do you plan on achieving? Just add the creation of a custom widget to a UI definition file just for the sake of doing so? I see no goal on doing that.

Comment: @JoséFonte I have a project where I use some custom widgets. Because the rest of the window is defined using UI definition files it would be kinda hacky to add one single widget from Vala

Comment: @stunningpotato I don't see why it would be hacky... Ultimately you would want to add that custom widget to glade, that is the correct path. If that is a lot of work, just add your custom widget, programmatically,  to the container you would retrieve from GtkBuilder. Not hacky at all.

Comment: I do not agree that creating a dummy instance is the right solution. It shouldn't be needed and might even be optimised out in some languages unless you get creative... @andlabs: The `type-func` attribute in the `GtkBuilder` `.ui` file *should* work... At least, I feel like a saw a bug going past that would have fixed it. Besides that, according to an experienced GNOME dev, if `type-func` isn't usable, then the answer is to invoke `typeof (Gtk.Whatever)` in Vala code: https://debarshiray.wordpress.com/2017/08/29/gtkbuilder-vala-and-webkit/

Comment: Agree that 22219788 is not a duplicate. Getting the widget into glade is not the same as getting `GtkBuilder` to correctly load it. I arrived at this question having accomplished the latter (getting it into glade) but failing on the former (loading the created glade file).

Comment: @underscore_d I can confirm that `type-func="mycustomwidget_get_type"` added to the UI definition file correctly solved this same problem for me.

Comment: The `type-func` isn't working for me. I create a `FooBarWidget`, check the built source, find that it transpiles to have the function `foo_bar_widget_get_type`, but if I replace `class="FooBarWidget"` with `type-func="foo_bar_widget_get_type"` then I get `Invalid object in ui file` and if I have both then I get `Invalid type function 'foo_bar_widget_get_type'` (and Debarshi's blog does say that it won't work with Vala). I can't get `typeof(FooBarWidget)` working either. Using Vala 0.48.5.